# How to change color of products on a website?

Tags: html

I am attempting to build a website that displays clothes such as t-shirts and pullovers. What I want is there to be an option to change the color of the products like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1y3y.png).
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?  Assume for a moment that nobody here can see your screen or knows what you're working on and that you actually have to describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: Dare I ask, what have you tried?

Comment: You are probably trying to build an e-commerce (that sells clothing?) kind of website, and while displaying the images, you want to have some controls that shows the same apparel in different colors and on different models (male/female). So, can you afford different images (.png files or .jpg files) for each color / gender combination, or do you need to do it programmatically (ie, you have only one image).

Comment: @user3392439: `"clothing"` - I really hope you're right before the question gets updated with screen shots of the problem...

Comment: @user3392439 Yes, precisely! Sorry for being so vague. I'm really new at this. *embarrassed*
I have different images for every color and model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need this for a website, You can easily do it with a bit of HTML and Javascript.

```
<div id = "clothes">
    <img src="#" id= "clothing">
    <button onclick= "change()">Click here</button>
    <button onclick = "change2()"> Click here</button>
    <button onclick = "change3()"> Click here</button>
</div>
```

Now for your Javascript do:

```
function change(){
  clothing.src = "#"; 
}
function change2(){
  clothing.src = "#"; 
}
function change3(){
  clothing.src = "#"; 
}
```

For more information about functions see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)

Hope this helps!